# Problem with grub update

Tags: grub2, updates, uuid

I really  start hating grub, because  obviously updating grub is kind of  a gamble. I did a normal update of grub from Ubuntu, and there was no error message or question or whatever, but after rebooting it now boots  from the wrong disk.

When I look into the fstab, I see there  are comments like "...was on nvme-bla during installation..". I'm not sure why the update thought it to be  a good idea to move boot to another disk, probably the developers thought it would be funny. Also I really don't understand why it didn't just comment the old entries, probably to make it more difficult to repair.

Where do I get the UUIDs from to reboot from the correct disk? It would take me 2-3 days to restore from backups, so please help someone.

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/uuid_storage_devices_linux/  -> `sudo blkid`, alternatively `lsblk -o TYPE,NAME,PARTUUID | grep -v loop`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658/linux-how-can-i-view-all-uuids-for-all-available-disks-on-my-system

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Hannu was correct, the following steps helped me to solve the problem:

0. I physically removed the other disk
1. I got the UUIDs like Hannu described, thx !!!
2. I remounted the device, because it was mounted as read-only
3. I edited the fstab with the UUIDs
4. Then I was able to boot
5. I updated and reinstalled GRUB

Now it boots again

P.S. Still this is the second time a grub-update broke my computer, they should really improve the strategy